# php simple function remove from characters of a word

Tags: php

I need a simple function(e.g function_cut) to cut from a variable characters if the number of characters is bigger than 14.
For example the current $user has 18 characters and I need to cut 4 of them (doesn't matter which one).

```
 $user = "abc123abc123abc123";

 $user = function_cut($user);
```

Comment: You mean that you'll just cut any 4 characters from the string?  Do you wan it to be random or can you just cut the first 4 or the last 4 for simplicity of implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
$first_14_characters = substr( $string, 0, 14 );
```

Comment: +1: To counter the down-vote as yo were the first answerer, though not elaborate.

Comment: Wow. Tough crowd today! @Everyone - the first answer to say `substr` should be the correct one, regardless of whether or not an example was provided. Move on! :p

Answer (score 2):

[`substr($user, 0, 14)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: @shamittomar I am pretty sure the OP knows to add a semicolon himself. Besides you don't always need a semicolon

Comment: I did not downvote your answer. I just explained you why somebody might have done that. But you downvoting my answer is just silly revenge, when you don't even know who did it.

Comment: What is so wrong with my answer that it got me 3 downvotes? I call shenanigans.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $user = "abc123abc123abc123";
    $user = substr($user, 0, 14);
?>
```

Comment: @Aillyn, I did not downvote your answer. I just explained you why somebody did that. I answered this because at the time I posted, nobody was elaborate.

Comment: Sorry about that. It still the same answer as everyone else's. I removed my downvote though.

Comment: Just because two people write the same answer at the same time but one is faster submitting it, that does not excuces a downvote!

Comment: @Kau-Boy, @Aillyn: Yes, and I have already hit my daily reputation cap. So, any upvoting does not bother me now. I am just addicted to SO. Maybe it's time to take the day off :)

Answer (score 1):

All the solutions are fine, but if you have UTF8 data, you should use the multibyte versions of the function, namely [mb_substr](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php):

```
function cut($str){ 
  return mb_substr($str, 0, 14); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function like this:

```
function cut($str){
  return substr($str, 0, 14);
}

$user = cut($user);
echo $user;
```

Comment: This is wrong, it will remove the last 4 characters regardless of string length and that's clearly not what the question asks

Comment: Sneaky edit. You had `substr($str, 0, -4)`, then `substr($str, 0, strlen($str)-4)`

Comment: @Ailyn: Not wrong still, user clearly said: **For example the current $user has 18 characters and I need to cut 4 of them (doesn't matter which one).** I modified to cope with people like you :)

Comment: No, he said he had a problem when the username was longer than 14 characters, which means he wants to remove trim the string to 14 characters, not `strlen($user)-4` characters

Comment: @Ailyn: Ok let's close this here :)